# Issue deleting items with filter search

Tags: cakephp, search, cakephp-2.4

I am developing a plugin for CakePHP 2.

My problem is below:

I have a view with a filter search, where users can search by category:

```
<div>   
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Permission'); ?>
<fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->input("permissionCategory", array('label' => 
__d('permission_manager','Categoría'), 'options' => $categorias, 'empty' => 
__d('permission_manager','-- Categorías --'), 'default' => '','class' => 'select-cat', 'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()')); ?>
</fieldset>
<?php //echo $this->Form->end(__d('permission_manager','Aceptar')); ?>
</div>
```

When I do click over delete button, it shows the confirm message, but when I push yes, the item is not deleted.

I realized it has relation with the action. Maybe with the request type.

The action code:

```
public function index() {
  $this->paginate = array('order' => 'Permission.category asc, Permission.code asc');
  $this->Permission->recursive = 2;

  if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if(empty($this->request->data['Permission']['permissionCategory'])) {
      $conditions = null;
    } else {
      $cat = $this->Permission->findById($this->request->data['Permission']
      ['permissionCategory']);
      $conditions = array('Permission.category ' => $cat['Permission']['category']);
    }
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions );    
  }
  $this->set('categorias', $this->Permission->find('list', array('fields' => 'category', 
  'group' => 'category')));
  $this->set('permissions', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

Edit:

My delete button:

(I have one like this for row in DB)

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink($this->Html->image('PermissionManager.cross.png', 
  array('title' => 
  __d('permission_manager','Borrar'))),'delete/'.h($permission['Permission']['id']), 
  array( 'escape' => false), __d('permission_manager','Are you sure... ?'));
?>
```

My delete action:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Permission->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Permission->exists()) {
        //throw new NotFoundException(__d('permission_manager','Permiso inexistente'));
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__d('permission_manager','Permiso inexistente'), 'default', array('class'=>'error'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
    if ($this->Permission->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__d('permission_manager','El permiso ha sido borrado correctamente.'), 'default', array('class'=>'success'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__d('permission_manager','El permiso no ha podido borrarse. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.'), 'default', array('class'=>'error'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

Comment: where is the delete button in your view? And where is the delete action?

Comment: @arilia sorry I forgot include it. I edited the post. Could you help me?

Comment: why you use a postLink and not a simple link whene you are just passing the id in the url and no post data are passed to your delete action? Do you get any flash message after you click confirm?

Comment: Ok! You fixed my problem!. Only a question: which is the normal situation to use the postLink? Thanks!

Comment: when you want to pass post data to your action in one simple click. When you have an action that accepts only post data and you want to pass an array data to it but you don't want your user to fill an entire form. Actually it's just a pre-filled form created by cake

Comment: @Luis why do you have 'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()' in your input?